PowerBi Matrix Table (Or Excel) - Compare 2 different variables of same object (different Columns) in a Pivot Table/Matrix
I am using PowerBi and am trying to solve a problem of comparing the outcomes of 2 columns that are showing the same object but with 2 possible outcomes.  I will then do some analyse on percentage changes, differences and a bunch of other stuff with extended dataset    Simplifying the main problem's see below:



ID
Apples
Apples -1




C1
1
0


C2
2
1


C3
4
3


C4
5
4


C5
6
5


C6
4
3


C7
3
2


C8
2
1


C9
2
1


C10
1
0



Problem is when I put table into a matrix (pivot table) my total is always 10 which is fine but my count of apples is always the same in relation to how many people have 1 or 2 apples if i use "Apples" column and put values as Apples and Apples-1.  Eg output would look like:



Apples
Apples
Apples -1




1
2
2


2
3
3


3
1
1


4
2
2


5
1
1


6
1
1



Desired Pivot result (2nd and 3rd columns are value counts)



Apples
Apples
Apples -1




0
0
2


1
2
3


2
3
1


3
1
2


4
2
1


5
1
1


6
1
0



I have tried all sorts but can't figure out how to get the desired count in column 2 and 3 of pivot.  used Apples-1 to get 0 to 6 in rows but result is same in that count is same for both 2nd and 3rd column!  What do I need to do to get the 0 in first (Apples) column if using "Apples" as Rows.  tried to duplicate Table and connect with Dim table that has 1 to 6 but that got confusing quick and didn't work!  Any ideas, what am I doing wrong!!!  I get that it's something to do with IDs but how do I get it to adjust?
